# Duplicate socket.io info and use it for a game

Tags: node.js, sockets, svg

So I am working on a game that should be able to implement some stuff from a websocket feed with live data running on socket.io. Now the data is coming from another company that asked us only to connect with a single connection so I need to duplicate some of the data to our own server and then distribute it to our game from there. They are willing to send the data over TCP or UDP if I cannot find another way. But it would be easier for them if I could find a way with this info they already provide through this websocket feed.

I am kinda new to networking and especially to socket.io. I have done some research but I couldn't find much information. I know I cannot just copy socket.io to my own server but they visualize the info I need to  in html. I thought maybe I can connect to this html page with php, copy the svg info and then distribute this to our game. Would this be possible? Before I spend hours researching something that is not even possible, I like to know if someone has any previous experience in a project like this?

Thanks in advance, if something about my question is not clear please ask! I will add extra info if possible!

EDIT: Meanwhile I tried duplicating the html code with this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://theurltocopy.com:3000/';

$html = file_get_contents( $url);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
echo $html; 
?>
```

But while it does copy most info from the page, it does seem to leave out all the live data. SO this doesn't seem to be a useful option I guess

Comment: i did not understand why you are trying to copy also the frontend from the url. If you need data from another company i'm pretty sure that they also have some sort of API that can return you all the data that you need

Comment: Thanks for the info max